# Redirect Old URLs To new URL (subdirectory to main directory)

Tags: javascript, jquery, .htaccess, url

I have a website on my subdirectory.
My all URL was `mywebsite.com/sub/page-or-post-link`

I have moved my site to the main directory. `mywebsite.com`.

I want to redirect my old link to new links.

Like if someone searches `mywebsite.com/sub/a-post-or-page`.

They should redirect to `mywebsite.com/a-post-or-page`

**How can I do this with javascript, jquery, or with changing .hraccess?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use RewriteRule in .htaccess file. This one should make a job:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^sub/(.*)$ http://mywebsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```